# I am getting the following assertion error in junit

Tags: java, spring, junit

This is my test case:

```
public class SearchStudentDetailsServiceImpl  extends JunitCommonUtil  {

    @Test
    public void searchStudentDetails()
    {   
        StudentDetailsSearch studentDetailsSearch=new StudentDetailsSearch();
        String sortFlag = "name";
        UserService userService = (UserService) ServiceLocator.getInstance()
                                                     .getBean("userService");
        StringSearchField srchFld = new StringSearchField();
        srchFld.setValue("stu1");
        studentDetailsSearch.setId(srchFld);
        userService.searchStudentDetails(studentDetailsSearch, sortFlag);
        assertEquals("Result", "stu1", studentDetailsSearch.getId());
    }
}
```

The error i am getting while running junit test case:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Result expected:<stu1> but was:<com.intertek.domain.StringSearchField@740edac1>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:647)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:128)
    at com.intertek.test.SearchStudentDetailsServiceImpl.searchStudentDetails(SearchStudentDetailsServiceImpl.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: can you please share the methods you are calling?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got the error:

I replaced

```
assertEquals("Result", "stu1", studentDetailsSearch.getId());
```

with

```
assertEquals("Result", "stu1", studentDetailsSearch.getId().getValue());
```